# Is there an audio commentary for Ghost In The Shell series and movies?

Tags: ghost-in-the-shell-sac, ghost-in-the-shell, ghost-in-the-shell-arise

I'd like to know if there are audio commentaries from the creators of GITS series and movies. Of all the things I've seen GITS has the most unexplained moments, so I'd like to find out what those things could mean. I'm also interested in commentary for the new Arise series.

I also think asking a bunch of separate questions might not be the best idea, so I'd like to find out some answers by myself listening to the commentary track(s).

Comment: Asking a bunch of separate questions is this site's raison d'être.

Comment: @coleopterist well, I'm not sure if it'll be worth it, but I'll try and write down everything I'd like to know the next time I'm rewatching the whole thing and see if something might be interesting for others. You know, there's a close reason for questions that won't probably help any future visitors, so I'm just trying to avoid that.

Comment: I don't know all versions, but at least in my DVD-Box (SAC), there were only some interviews with the team, no direct commentaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [a page](http://gabrielarobin.com/1738/ghost-in-the-shellsac-blu-ray-box-release) that lists Blu-Ray sets you can buy for SAC, and those contain audio commentaries. That indicates that there are audio commentaries, but I'm not sure if they can be gotten not on the Blu-Ray set. As far as I can tell, there is no audio commentary for *Arise*, but considering that it hasn't been released on any sort of disc form, that might change.

On [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_in_the_Shell_%28film%29), it says about the original Ghost in the Shell film that:

> Manga Entertainment released the film on Blu-ray on November 24, 2009; this version contains the original film and the remastering, but omits the audio commentary and face-to-face interview with Oshii which was listed on its box.

But from what I can tell, the 2004 DVD release and the 2007 Blu-Ray releases have the commentary, and the 2004 special edition also included things like character dossiers and a creator's biography.

Comment: Arise hasn't been fully released yet, maybe they'll add commentary in future when there are more episodes.

Comment: That's what I figured.